# How do i Dump contents of Vector into a new file?

Tags: java, linux

Here is my program to calculate prime numbers that are before 92. It works like a charm. I want my output to be put into a new file called VectorDump instead of it just being displayed on the regular screen. Where would I start this in my program here? Below is my code and the output of my code is at the bottom of the page.

- This is the output that I get

The primes before 92 are:

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
73 79 83 89

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeByVector
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                final int NUMBER_PER_LINE = 10;
                int count = 0;
//              java.util.Vector vector = new java.util.Vector();
                Vector vector = new Vector();
                System.out.println("The primes before 92 are: \n");

                for (int n = 2; n < 92; n++)

                  PrintWriter writer = null;
                        try{
                                writer = new PrintWriter("VectorDump", "UTF-8");
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                      break;
}
                        Iterator it = vector.iterator();
                      while(it.hasNext())
                {
                        writer.print(
                     it.next() + " "
                );
                }
                writer.close();
{
                        boolean isPrime = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
                        {
                                int primeNumber =
                                        ((Integer)(vector.elementAt(i))).intValue();
                                if (primeNumber > Math.sqrt(n)) break;

                                if (n % primeNumber == 0)
                                {
                                        isPrime = false;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
if (isPrime)
                        {
                                count ++;
                                vector.addElement(new Integer(n));
                                if (count % NUMBER_PER_LINE == 0)
                                {
                                        System.out.println(n);
                                }
                                else
                                        System.out.print(n + " ");

                        }
                }
        }
}



PrimeByVector.java:15: error: not a statement
                  PrintWriter writer = null;
                  ^
PrimeByVector.java:15: error: ';' expected
                  PrintWriter writer = null;
                             ^
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after your first `for` (not in for body!!)  loop:

```
          PrintWriter writer = null;
          try {
              writer = new PrintWriter("VectorDump", "UTF-8");
          } catch (Exception e) {
              break;
          }

            Iterator it = vector.iterator();

          while(it.hasNext())
          {
           writer.print(
                     it.next() + " "
              );
          }

          writer.close();
```

Comment: Immediately after the "first" for loop?

Comment: After this loop: 
                for (int n = 2; n < 92; n++)

Comment: remove ';' from it.next() + " ";

Comment: Sorry, I will not help you anymore if you don't know the basics.

Comment: I am not familiar with PrintWriter, I know that writer is an instance of the PrintWriter, and we are setting it to null, but I don't understand why its not a statement.

Comment: Immediately after your first for (not in for body!!) loop:

Comment: Im sure you are frustrated with me, everywhere I move it too I get even more errors than before. sorry :/ im so lost on where its supposed to go...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hBB6Q3mj 
This is waht you want. On my environment it compiles and works well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of print it to `System.out` use a `FileOutputStream` instead and everything should work.

Don't forget to call `close()` on the outputstream.

Comment: so would I need to import some more libraries too then?

Comment: @Michael You have an Intenet connection and a lead with you. Why don't you try searching?

Comment: @Michael no this is all part of the JDK